# Linked dylibs built for retain/release but object files built for GC-only for architecture i386

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, garbage-collection

When I am trying to build my application, I get this error message:

```
ld: Linked dylibs built for retain/release but object files built for GC-only for architecture i386
```

I use libssh2 library, for i386 architecture, I have no idea what the problem is! 
Sorry if is a stupid question!

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that some of the linked classes use retain/release patterns, but your app is being built for garbage collection only (OS X's automated retain/releases that are more efficient and easier for you). So remove your retain/releases, or turn off garbage collection for the app. Keep in mind that a third party library may be part of the problem. Let me know if you need more details!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your xcode name like "xcode 5.1, Xcode 4.6" then change to "Xcode" and try to building, I have worked this

Actually the framework path is related with Xcode name. So please try this